# Segmentation fault when trying to dereference pointer to linked list class

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, segmentation-fault, singly-linked-list

I'm getting a segementation fault when trying to dereference a pointer to my linked list class:

```
#include <iostream> //to use cin and cout
#include <string>   //to use strings
#include <cstdlib>  //to use string functions
#include <vector>   //to use vector data structure
#include <fstream>  //to operate on files
#include <iomanip>  //read: input/output manipulation
#include "LinkedList.hpp" //linked list header file

using namespace std;

int main(){

vector<string> textVec;
ifstream Graph;
Graph.open("Graph.txt");

string chr;

//create vector from Graph.txt
while(Graph >> chr){
    textVec.push_back(chr);
}

int n = stoi(textVec[0]);
int m = stoi(textVec[1]);

int index = 2;

//create adjacency table
LinkedList * adjTbl[n];

LinkedList * tempList = new LinkedList();

tempList -> printList();

return 0;
}
```

LinkedList.hpp:

```
#include <iostream> //to use cout
#include <iomanip> //to format output
#include <string> //to use strings

using namespace std;

//struct Node represents some Node information

struct Node
{
    int vertex;
    int weight;
    bool notUsed;
    struct Node * next;
};

//class LinkedList will contains a linked list of nodex
class LinkedList
{   
    public:
    struct Node * head;
    LinkedList();
    ~LinkedList();
    bool insertEdge(int v, int w);
    bool removeElement(string clubName, string univName);
    void printList();
};

//Constructor to initialize the linked list
LinkedList::LinkedList()
{
    struct Node * head = new Node;
    head = NULL;
}

//Description: adds a node to the linked list with the given information 
bool LinkedList::insertEdge(int v, int w)
{
   
struct Node * cursor;        //defining a cursor to begin looking for index

struct Node * bef;           //defining and initializing a cursor to help look for index
bef = head;

struct Node * element = new Node; 
element -> vertex = v;
element -> weight = w;
element -> next = NULL;

if(head == NULL){     //in case linked list is empty
    head = element;
    return true;
}

else if(w < head -> weight && head != NULL){     //in case element wants to be the head of a list with at least one elements
    element -> next = head;
    head = element;
    return true;
}

else if(head != NULL){    //in case elements wants to be somewhere on a filled list

    cursor = head -> next;

    do{     //while loop looking for end of list
            
        if(w < cursor -> weight){   //stop at element before where we want to add element
            element -> next = bef -> next; //reconnecting next addresses to insert new element and returning true
            bef -> next = element;
            return true;
        }
        else if(cursor -> next == NULL){
            cursor -> next = element;
            return true;
        }

        cursor = cursor -> next;
        bef = bef -> next;
            
    }while(cursor != NULL && v < cursor -> vertex);
}
return false;                           
}

//Description: prints out linked list club and university names

void LinkedList::printList(){
  
struct Node * cursor;  //defining and initializing a cursor to begin looking through list
cursor = head;

if(cursor == NULL){
    cout << "null cursor";
}
while(cursor != NULL){
        
    cout << "vertex: " << cursor -> vertex << ", weight: " << cursor -> weight << "\n";
        
    cursor = cursor -> next;
        
}
}
```

the exact error I get is:

```
 /bin/sh: line 1: 42771 Segmentation fault: 11  

[Done] exited with code=139 in 1.378 seconds
```

I tried plugging the code into OnlineGDP to just test out a different IDE and got a different error:

```
from LinkedList.hpp:12,
from LinkedList.hpp:12,
...about a hundred more times...
from Assignment7.cpp:12:
/usr/include/c++/9/cstdlib:41:28: error: #include nested too deeply
   41 | #include <bits/c++config.h>
      |        
In file included from LinkedList.hpp:12,...(a hundred more times)
LinkedList.hpp:6:42: error: #include nested too deeply
    6 | #include <iostream> //to use cin and cout
      |                                          ^
LinkedList.hpp:7:37: error: #include nested too deeply
    7 | #include <string>   //to use strings
      |                                     ^
LinkedList.hpp:8:46: error: #include nested too deeply
    8 | #include <cstdlib>  //to use string functions
      |                                              ^
LinkedList.hpp:9:51: error: #include nested too deeply
    9 | #include <vector>   //to use vector data structure
      |                                                   ^
LinkedList.hpp:10:42: error: #include nested too deeply
   10 | #include <fstream>  //to operate on files
      |                                          ^
LinkedList.hpp:11:54: error: #include nested too deeply
   11 | #include <iomanip>  //read: input/output manipulation
      |                                                      ^
LinkedList.hpp:12:52: error: #include nested too deeply
   12 | #include "LinkedList.hpp" //linked list header file
      |                                                    ^
In file included from LinkedList.hpp:12,...
```

I've tried chopping and changing the code a few times and cant seem to avoid getting this error. Also, over the course of writing this my printList function has gone from working - to a segmentation fault, which leads me to believe that it was something to do with the way the linked listed is being stored in dynamic memory, but other than that I'm stumped. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Stumped? Debugger can help with that, did you try to step through the code?

Comment: Header lacks include guards. It looks a lot like you have LinkedList.hpp including LinkedList.hpp in the online gdb version.

Comment: How sure are you that `Graph.open("Graph.txt");` succeeded?

Comment: `head` in your constructor is a local variable not the member variable. The member variable is therefore uninitialised

Comment: Your constructor is incorrect. The first line declares a new variable named `head` which shadows, or hides, the member variable and points it at a new object. The next line set the same local variable to NULL leaking memory. `Node` should have a constructor that initializes its `next` pointer to NULL. You don't need to add `struct` everywhere like `struct Node`, you're writing C++, not C.